# IntelliJ Dependency Management with Java 9 Modules and Maven - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-module

I am still fairly new to Java, and am trying to restructure one of my Java projects for the Java 9 module structure, and it seems like I need to do everything completely manually. I am hoping I am simply missing some steps somewhere in the correct way to be handling my dependencies:

Old Way (Java 8 and older)

1. I create my project.
2. I add my dependencies to the pom
3. I code.
4. I compile.

New Way (modules)?

1. I create my project.
2. I create my modules.
3. I create a project level .pom that defines my dependencies for all of the modules
4. I manually add each dependency to each module it will be used in. If I need to update a dependency, I remove the old one from each module and put the new one in, after updating the Maven .pom (this means someone cloning my project from git has to figure out all the dependencies as well, since .iml files aren't just a list of dependencies and don't generally get put on git)
5. I manually add every possible package a module might need to the module-info file, since there is no autocomplete otherwise, once again, manually updating the list of requires statements if the dependency is changed.
6. I code.
7. I remove all of the unused packages from the module-info file.
8. I compile the code.

This just seems inefficient. Is there a better / correct way I should be doing this? This is the process that their documentation indicates I should be using. ( see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies )

Yes, I know I don't have to add all the packages manually and can just search on the command line to figure out where a class I want to use is located, but that just takes even longer.

Comment: Do you have a multi-module(maven module to clarify) structure or is it just a single module that you've been talking about in the question? And in your former approach is that as well a multi-module project? Seems like the comparison is between two different approaches. With java-module, the only addition should have been `module-info.java`, nothing else.

Comment: @nullpointer if you mean in the maven pom.xml, it is just a single module. Should I be defining each of my Java modules in the pom?

Comment: Having one maven module per java-module would make much sense is what I wanted to point out as well.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a ton, this fixed me up and finally made sense!